# Chain rule states that $\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} $. What are the restrictions that x, y and t follow for this rule to be true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the question states, what are the restrictions on the choice of $y$ in the chain rule?

Answer (score 1):

From the proof of chain rule you can conclude that the only restrictions are

1. $x(y)$ is differentiable at $y(t)$
2. $y(t)$ is differentiable at $t$

Comment: Is it possible that $y(t)$ is not differentiable at $t$, $f(t) = x(y(t)) = 0$, and the chain rule still valid in a neighborhood around $t$ in which $f(t)$ is differentiable?  What you're saying seems obvious from the statement of the chain rule as $f'(t) = y'(t) \cdot x'(y(t))$ but I'm not sure there aren't any exceptions.

Comment: For example, how do we classify $x(t) = t^2$, $y(t) = \vert t \vert$, $f(t) = x(y(t)) = t^2$?  $y(t)$ isn't differentiable at $t = 0$ but the chain rule still works to find $f'(t) = 2 \cdot t$ because $x'(y(0)) = 0$ and it doesn't matter what $y'(0)$ is defined to be.

Comment: @Dan Brumleve The chain rule does not cover such situations. It only gives a sufficient but not necessary condition for $dy/dt = (dy/dx)(dx/dx)$ to work.